# Matrix multiplication of natural numbers

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I know matrix multiplication of matrices with real numbers is bounded by $ \Omega (n^2 log(n))$, but what about if all numbers are natural? Can we use the same methods to get a lower bound for this case and how should I do this? Also, what is the current known bound for this case?